# Add custom metrics for Scanner

Tags: sonarqube

I'm trying to add a custom metric to SonarQube, but everytime I run my sensor I get the following error:

```
 Metric should not be computed by a Sensor
```

What I did is create a custom metric in the admin interface, set its valuetype to Integer and used its key to add the computed value to a `InputFile` in the sensor.

If that is not the correct way to do it, I would be glad if someone can guide me in the correct direction :-)

I'm building a plugin for a legacy language and want to calculate the `Fan in` and `Fan out` values for modules (files).
They tell how often a module gets called and how many modules it is calling.

Answer (score 0):

I've found [examples](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-plugin-example/tree/master/src/main/java/org/sonarsource/plugins/example/measures) on Github which do exactly what I want :-)

One thing I had stumbled upon was that I still had to create the custom metrics in the admin menu, so that the metric key exists beforehand.